# Definition of Cayley's Theorem and embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

One question came in mind to relate Cayley's theorem and embeddings.

Can we say:

If $G$ is a group, then there exists an injective homomorphism $\phi : G \mapsto S_n$ for some $n$

is an alternative definition of Cayley's theorem? why yes or not?

I'm looking forward to your help.
Thanks.

Comment: An embedding **is** an injective group homomorphism, so, the answer is yes!

Comment: First, you don’t “define” theorems. You seem to be asking whether it is an equivalent *formulation* of Cayley’s Theorem.
The answer is “not quite”. Because this statement is false for infinite groups, but Cayley’s Theorem holds for *any* group, finite or infinite. It is equivalent to Cayley’s Theorem for **finite** groups.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin  Thank you so much for the comment, if I make the homomorphism from $\phi : G \mapsto S_X$ for a set $X$, does that make it equivalent to Cayley’s Theorem for finite groups and infinite groups ?.

Comment: Yes. But all you are doing is replacing “embedding” by the equivalent term “injective homomorphism”.

Comment: Yes! that's what I wanted. Thank you very much.